# why the cast is failing?

Tags: java

I am trying to do this

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("one");
stringList.add("two");
stringList.add("three");

(String[]) stringList.toArray();
```

why does this gives me class cast exception ?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

Comment: why use an arraylist if you ultimately want an array? Start with an array and add elements to it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better try this other [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29):

```
String[] stringArray = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
```

In that way the array returned is of the exact type that you need, no cast needed. The [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) you're invoking returns an `Object[]`, not a `String[]` and the cast you're trying to perform is invalid.

Comment: and even better use `new String[stringList.size()]`.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why your code fails is because `.toArray()` returns an array of type `Object[]`, which you cannot cast down into a `String[]`. To fix it, use the other `toArray(T[] a)` i.e.

`stringList.toArray(new String[0]);`

Answer (score 3):

Because `toArray()` method of `List` class returns `Object[]` not `String[]`, and you cannot cast from `Object[]` to `String[]`. However, the right way to do it is:

```
String[] array = new String[stringList.size()];
stringList.toArray(array);
```

or:

```
String[] array = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast to a String array. You want:

String[] test = stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);

Answer (score 2):

The `ArrayList<T>.toArray()` method returns an array of type `Object`, since that is a perfectly acceptable thing to do.  In fact, because of type-erasure, it's the only thing it can do.

If you want to get an array of type `String`, then call the `ArrayList<T>.toArray(T[])` method.  In your case, you would call it like this:

```
stringList.toArray(new String[3]);
```

Calling it like that will stuff the `ArrayList` contents into the provided `String` array.